# ng-grid editCell not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

when i double click on a cell it lets me edit the value, but when i start typing it deletes the complete value and only lets me type 1 character.

Anyone experienced this issue?

```
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
        multiSelect: true,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        enableCellSelection: false,
        keepLastSelected: false,
        showFilter : true,
        enableColumnResize : true,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        columnDefs: [{field: 'show', displayName: '', enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate: '<span class="ngCellText cursor-pointer" style="padding-left: 15px;" ng-click=navEdit(row.getProperty(\'naam\'),row.getProperty(\'crediteurnummer\'));><i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></span>'},
                {field: 'naam', displayName: 'naam', enableCellEdit: true}, 
                {field: 'crediteurnummer', displayName:'crediteurnummer', enableCellEdit: true},
                {field: 'plaatsnaam', displayName:'plaatsnaam', enableCellEdit: true},
                {field: 'land', displayName:'land', enableCellEdit: true},
                {field: 'waardering', displayName: 'waardering', cellTemplate: '<div class="{{row.entity.waardering}} ngCellText">{{row.entity.waardering}}</div>', enableCellEdit: true}], 
                rowTemplate:'<div style="height: 100%; color: #428bca;" ><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
                '<div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }"> </div>' +
                '<div ng-cell></div>' +
                '</div></div>'
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

changed is to 'enableCellEditOnFocus' and now works perfectly. not a correct solution, but it does the job.